# imap_dfr to bind_rows from list of lists in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use `bind_rows` in an `imap_dfr` function. I have lists of lists such that I want to bind together the results from "1", "650" and "1300" (which are all data frames). I am trying with the `map_dfr` function but cannot seem to get it working. I am also trying to create a new column "model" which contains the list of lists it occured in.

```
x2 <- imap_dfr(
  shap_values_results[[1]][[1]]$shap_score,
  shap_values_results[[1]][[650]]$shap_score,
  shap_values_results[[1]][[1300]]$shap_score,
  .f = bind_rows,
  .id = "model"
)
```

I get this message:

> Error: Argument 1 must have names

Where am I going wrong? I would like to create a single data frame with each of the list of lists rows binded together.

If I use:

```
x2 <- bind_rows(
  shap_values_results[[1]][[1]]$shap_score,
  shap_values_results[[1]][[650]]$shap_score,
  shap_values_results[[1]][[1300]]$shap_score
)
```

I can get a data frame of the lists binded together but I lack / miss the list "ID" from where that data frame came from.

(I am working on filtering the data down to `dput()` it here.)

EDIT:

Structure of the list:

```
> str( shap_values_results[[1]][[1]]$shap_score)
'data.frame':   2190 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ holiday              : num  -0.306 -0.281 -0.254 -0.248 -0.247 ...
 $ temp                 : num  -0.0853 -0.025 -0.0735 0.0177 0.0672 ...
 $ wind                 : num  -0.5213 0.1489 0.605 0.1408 0.0605 ...
 $ humidity             : num  0.11052 0.15571 -0.00248 0.12065 0.17133 ...
 $ barometer            : num  -0.0268 -0.0361 -0.0957 -0.0236 -0.0213 ...
 $ weekday              : num  0.0742 0.0918 0.0357 0.0882 0.0921 ...
 $ weekend              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ workday_on_holiday   : num  -0.000757 -0.000757 -0.003148 -0.000757 -0.000757 ...
 $ weekend_on_holiday   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ protocol_active      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ text_fog             : num  0.02891 0.0357 0.00851 0.03118 0.02916 ...
 $ text_light_rain      : num  0.0392 0.0362 0.0362 0.0396 0.0394 ...
 $ text_mostly_cloudy   : num  -0.00406 -0.00931 -0.00662 -0.02493 -0.01843 ...
 $ text_passing_clouds  : num  -0.001616 -0.001324 -0.012845 -0.000541 -0.001381 ...
 $ text_rain            : num  0.00735 -0.00494 -0.01891 -0.00494 -0.00494 ...
 $ text_scattered_clouds: num  -0.1 -0.123 -0.217 -0.128 -0.107 ...
 $ text_sunny           : num  0.000442 0.000909 0.000277 -0.003121 -0.002015 ...
 $ month_1              : num  -0.0176 0.1267 0.0599 0.1313 0.1148 ...
 $ month_2              : num  0.02293 0.00719 -0.00393 0.09392 0.07848 ...
 $ month_3              : num  -0.023 -0.0329 -0.0335 -0.0163 -0.0073 ...
 $ month_4              : num  -0.1067 -0.1359 -0.1217 -0.126 -0.0669 ...
 $ month_5              : num  -0.0768 -0.1301 -0.2356 -0.1306 -0.0891 ...
 $ month_6              : num  -0.0574 -0.0162 -0.0284 -0.0361 -0.0418 ...
 $ month_7              : num  -0.0787 -0.0724 -0.0537 -0.066 -0.0683 ...
 $ month_8              : num  -0.0587 -0.0948 -0.0845 -0.0947 -0.0894 ...
 $ month_9              : num  0.0445 0.0603 0.0075 0.0609 0.0482 ...
 $ month_10             : num  0.0743 0.065 0.0573 0.0654 0.0741 ...
 $ month_11             : num  0.058 0.0215 0.0164 0.0251 0.0547 ...
 $ month_12             : num  0.165 0.245 0.102 0.19 0.143 ...
 $ BIAS0                : num  0.00241 0.00241 0.00241 0.00241 0.00241 ...
```

Comment: Added the structure of the list of lists.

Comment: I think `bind_rows` with the `.id` works...

Comment: My "problem" with the `bind_rows` method is that it creates a data frame with `.id` being "1", "2" and "3". I am hoping it would have created the `.id` column as "1", "650" and "1300".

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we are extracting the data.frame already from the `list` and there is no need for the `.f = bind_rows` in `imap_dfr`, instead it can be just a placeholder identity (`I`) after wrapping it in a `list`

```
out <- imap_dfr(list(`1` = 
      shap_values_results[[1]][[1]]$shap_score,
      `650` = shap_values_results[[1]][[650]]$shap_score,
      `1300` = shap_values_results[[1]][[1300]]$shap_score),
    .f = I,
   .id = "model"
   )
```

If we want the 'model' column to be the index, then place  it in a `list` and set the names  of the `list` with the same values

```
out <- bind_rows(list(`1` = shap_values_results[[1]][[1]]$shap_score,
      `650` = shap_values_results[[1]][[650]]$shap_score,
      `1300` = shap_values_results[[1]][[1300]]$shap_score), .id = 'model')
```

---

In addition to the above, it may be better to do this in a automatic way i.e. not repeating the extraction

```
map_dfr(set_names(shap_values_results[[1]][c(1, 650, 1300)], 
     unique(names(shap_values_results[[1]][c(1, 650, 1300)]))), ~ 
            .x$shap_score, .id = "model")
```

Comment: I get this error `Error in .f(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...) : 
  unused arguments (.y[[i]], shap_values_results[[1]][[650]]$shap_score, shap_values_results[[1]][[1300]]$shap_score)`

Comment: @user113156  I guess the first option should work now

Comment: The first option works great. However it is not dynamic to changes in the list data. Perhaps using `case_when` in a `dplyr` pipe would be sufficient.

Comment: @user113156  Please check the last option i just updated

Comment: @user113156  There is a limitation in testing the code

Comment: Yes! I think this worked for me: `outout <- map_dfr(set_names(shap_values_results[[1]][c(1, 650, 1300)],
                            unique(names(shap_values_results[[1]][c(1, 650, 1300)]))),
        ~ .x$shap_score, .id = "model")`

Comment: @user113156  I am updating my post with your version